# Compare Entity Framework to Sql Database

Tags: entity-framework, silverlight, entity-framework-4, edmx

I inadvertently restored an old database and lost my new schema. I already updated my entity framework from the "new" schema (now deleted), so I am to compare entity framework to the database (old schema) to see what is different and what tables/columns I need to add in the database. It is kind of a reverse of "Update Model from Database".  Currently "Generate Database from Model" throws an error so I cannot just create another db and compare the two databases.

Comment: The SSDL generated by the activity 'CsdlToSsdlAnMslActivity' is not valid and had the following errors: The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role.